# How to return two random rows using NEWID()?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using SQL Server 2008.

I have a query that pulls two random BikeIDs out of a table called Bikes.  The table looks like this:

```
 BikeID     BikeName
 1          Bob
 2          Cindy
 3          Carl
 4          Joe
 5          Jane
```

I use the NEWID() function to pull two random BikeIDs out like this:

```
SELECT     TOP 2 BikeID
FROM       Bikes
ORDER BY   NEWID()
```

My results look like this:

```
 Row - BikeID
 1     5
 2     1

 Row - BikeID
 1     3
 2     4

 Row - BikeID
 1     2
 2     5

 Row - BikeID
 1     3
 2     3
```

My problem is that I am coming up with duplicates, meaning I get the same number returned twice, see the last example resultset.  I am NOT SURE whether NEWID() can return the exact same number twice or not.  If not, then I must have a glitch elsewhere.

These are not actually the results that I am producing. These kinds of results appear on my web page that calls this query. So, I get duplicates on the web page. I have not reproduced these results using just SQL in the database query writer.

Is this the best or right way to get two random rows from a query?  Does NEWID() eliminate the possibility of return duplicates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't get duplicates because you can't select the same row twice in such a simple query.

So, the simple answer is you have 2 rows with `BikeID = 3`

Comment: Or the example query is not representative of what the OP is actually doing.

Comment: I don't have duplicate ids. I believe that my problem lies elsewhere in the system that generates the web page.

Comment: @Evik James: could be. However, that query on that table *will not* give duplicate rows. You can if there was a JOIN of course in your real query because of how rows multiply in JOINs. Is your posted query the actual query on actual data?

Comment: There is no join.  The table and query is pretty close to the real query.  I've tested the query and cannot get any duplicates, but the web page yields duplicates. I'm almost certain that the error is further down the line.

Comment: @Evik James: in which case this isn't a SQL Server problem at all. The question and tags are quite misleading

Comment: No, it's not misleading at all. I asked the question in pursuit of the answer. Your answer addresses my question. I am still left with the problem though. Your answer helped me determine that it's not a SQL problem, but must be something else.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a DISTINCT before BikeID